# Criar tabela Editável

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-datatables

Gostava de criar uma tabela em que as suas células possam ser editadas mas que cumpram uns certos requisitos. O que eu tenho é isto:

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="vendaTabela" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-class="expand">Cód.</th>
        <th data-hide="phone">Designação</th>
        <th data-hide="phone">Qnt.</th>
        <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Uni.</th>
        <th>Preço</th>
        <th>Desconto</th>
        <th>IVA</th>
        <th>Sub-Total</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
 </tbody>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(function () {
        $("td").dblclick(function () {
            var conteudoOriginal = $(this).text();
            $(this).addClass("celulaEmEdicao");
            $(this).html("<input type='text' value='" + conteudoOriginal + "' />");
            $(this).children().first().focus();
            console.log($(this).attr('id'));
            $(this).children().first().keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.which == 13) {
                    var novoConteudo = $(this).val();
                    $(this).parent().text(novoConteudo);
                    $(this).parent().removeClass("celulaEmEdicao");
                }
            });
            $(this).children().first().blur(function () {
                $(this).parent().text(conteudoOriginal);
                $(this).parent().removeClass("celulaEmEdicao");
            });


        });
    });
```

Tenho também um botão para adicionar novas linhas:

```
//ADICIONAR LINHA
    $("#btnAdd").click(function () {
        $('#vendaTabela').append('<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>');
    });
```

Quanto aos requisitos será melhor ir por fases:

1º- Gostava de arranjar uma forma de as células serem identificadas. Sei que posso colocar id's nos td's do HTML mas quando adiciono nova linha, como é que elas são identificadas?

2º- Como posso colocar função por colunas? Isto é, quero que a coluna 'Sub-Total' seja a multiplicação  da coluna 'Qnt.' com a coluna 'Preço'. Consigo fazer a função para a primeira linha já criada no HTML, mas, como fazer para quando adiciono outra linha ?

3º- Como posso colocar um autocomplete na coluna que quiser, por exemplo na coluna da 'Designação' ?

Comment: você pode adicionar um plugin ao projeto? neste caso eu aconselho utilizar o jsView para auxiliar.

Comment: Poder posso, mas não conheço esse plugin, tenho de pesquisar sobre o seu uso.

Comment: depois posto um exemplo sobre ele, vai ajudar no momento de adicionar uma nova linha já com alguns dados.

Comment: As linhas que adiciono serão sempre iniciadas vazias. Obrigado :)

Comment: postei uma maneira alternativa de fazer esta tabela utilizando jsViews, você pode dá uma olhada se tiver interrese.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Como eu disse mais acima, você pode fazer isto utilizando o jsViews, como no exemplo abaixo:

Para isto você precisará de uma Entidade que servira de modelo, no caso a seguinte:

```
{
    Codigo: "",
    Designacao: "",
    Quantidade: "",
    Unidade: "",
    Preco: "",
    Desconto: "",
    IVA: "",
    SubTotal: ""
}
```

Você terá os templates para cada estado da Row (Detalhes, Inserir e Criar):

```
<script id="tmplDetails" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <tr data-type="details">
        <td><input name="btEditar" type="button" value="Editar" /></td>
        <td>{{:Codigo}}</td>
        <td>{{:Designacao}}</td>
        <td>{{:Quantidade}}</td>
        <td>{{:Unidade}}</td>
        <td>{{:Preco}}</td>
        <td>{{:Desconto}}</td>
        <td>{{:IVA}}</td>
        <td>{{:SubTotal}}</td>
    </tr>
</script>

<script id="tmplEdit" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <tr data-type="edit">
        <td><input name="btSalvar" type="button" value="Salvar" /></td>
        <td><input name="txtCodigo" type="text" value="{{:Codigo}}" /></td>
        <td><input name="txtDesignacao" type="text" value="{{:Designacao}}" /></td>
        <td><input name="txtQuantidade" type="text" value="{{:Quantidade}}" /></td>
        <td><input name="txtUnidade" type="text" value="{{:Unidade}}" /></td>
        <td><input name="txtPreco" type="text" value="{{:Preco}}" /></td>
        <td><input name="txtDesconto" type="text" value="{{:Desconto}}" /></td>
        <td><input name="txtIVA" type="text" value="{{:IVA}}" /></td>
        <td><input name="txtSubTotal" type="text" value="{{:SubTotal}}" /></td>
    </tr>
</script>

<script id="tmplCreate" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <tr data-type="create">
        <td><input name="btSalvar" type="button" value="Salvar" /></td>
        <td><input name="txtCodigo" type="text" value="{{:Codigo}}" /></td>
        <td><input name="txtDesignacao" type="text" value="{{:Designacao}}" /></td>
        <td><input name="txtQuantidade" type="text" value="{{:Quantidade}}" /></td>
        <td><input name="txtUnidade" type="text" value="{{:Unidade}}" /></td>
        <td><input name="txtPreco" type="text" value="{{:Preco}}" /></td>
        <td><input name="txtDesconto" type="text" value="{{:Desconto}}" /></td>
        <td><input name="txtIVA" type="text" value="{{:IVA}}" /></td>
        <td><input name="txtSubTotal" type="text" value="{{:SubTotal}}" /></td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Lembrando que você pode usar operações aritimeticas no template, então `{{:Quantidade * Preco}}` é valido e pode ser utilizado no SubTotal.

Note que utilizei as propriedades do Modelo nos templates, desta forma sabemos como preencher o template.

por fim teremos o HTML da tabela em si:

```
<table id="vendaTabela">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th data-class="expand">Cód.</th>
            <th data-hide="phone">Designação</th>
            <th data-hide="phone">Qnt.</th>
            <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Uni.</th>
            <th>Preço</th>
            <th>Desconto</th>
            <th>IVA</th>
            <th>Sub-Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="btCreate" type="button" value="Criar" /></td>
            <td colspan="8"></td>
        </tr>
    <tfoot>
<table>
```

O Script abaixo está montando a tabela utilizando um Source, que no caso pode ser uma requisição AJAX, porém estou utilizando uma lista com 10 Entidades.

```
var documento = $(document);
var vendaTabela = $("#vendaTabela");
var tabelaBody = $("tbody", vendaTabela);

var tmplDetails = $.templates("#tmplDetails");
var tmplEdit = $.templates("#tmplEdit");
var tmplCreate = $.templates("#tmplCreate");

var entidades = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    entidades.push({
        Codigo: "Codigo" + i,
        Designacao: "Designacao" + i,
        Quantidade: "Quantidade" + i,
        Unidade: "Unidade" + i,
        Preco: "Preco" + i,
        Desconto: "Desconto" + i,
        IVA: "IVA" + i,
        SubTotal: "SubTotal" + i
    });
}

tabelaBody.empty();
$.each(entidades, function (indice, entidade) {
    var novaLinha = $(tmplDetails.render(entidade));
    novaLinha.data("Entidade", entidade);

    tabelaBody.append(novaLinha);
});

documento.on("click", "#vendaTabela input[name='btCreate']", function () {
    var novaEntidade = {};
    var novaLinha = $(tmplCreate.render(novaEntidade));
    novaLinha.data("Entidade", novaEntidade);

    tabelaBody.append(novaLinha);
});

documento.on("click", "#vendaTabela input[name='btEditar']", function () {
    var linha = $(this).closest("[data-type]");
    var entidade = linha.data("Entidade");
    var novaLinha = $(tmplCreate.render(entidade));
    novaLinha.data("Entidade", entidade);

    linha.replaceWith(novaLinha);    
});

documento.on("click", "#vendaTabela input[name='btSalvar']", function () {
    var linha = $(this).closest("[data-type]");
    var txtCodigo = $("[name='txtCodigo']", linha);
    var txtDesignacao = $("[name='txtDesignacao']", linha);
    var txtQuantidade = $("[name='txtQuantidade']", linha);
    var txtUnidade = $("[name='txtUnidade']", linha);
    var txtPreco = $("[name='txtPreco']", linha);
    var txtDesconto = $("[name='txtDesconto']", linha);
    var txtIVA = $("[name='txtIVA']", linha);
    var txtSubTotal = $("[name='txtSubTotal']", linha);

    var entidade = linha.data("Entidade");
    entidade.Codigo = txtCodigo.val();
    entidade.Designacao = txtDesignacao.val();
    entidade.Quantidade = txtQuantidade.val();
    entidade.Unidade = txtUnidade.val();
    entidade.Preco = txtPreco.val();
    entidade.Desconto = txtDesconto.val();
    entidade.IVA = txtIVA.val();
    entidade.SubTotal = txtSubTotal.val();    

    var novaLinha = $(tmplDetails.render(entidade));    
    novaLinha.data("Entidade", entidade);

    linha.replaceWith(novaLinha);

});
```

note que eu fiz o bind dos eventos utilizando o `on` direto no `document`, fiz isto para que estes eventos estejam disponiveis para elementos criados através do template.

pro fim o codigo na integra:

```js
var documento = $(document);
var vendaTabela = $("#vendaTabela");
var tabelaBody = $("tbody", vendaTabela);

var tmplDetails = $.templates("#tmplDetails");
var tmplEdit = $.templates("#tmplEdit");
var tmplCreate = $.templates("#tmplCreate");

var entidades = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    entidades.push({
        Codigo: "Codigo" + i,
        Designacao: "Designacao" + i,
        Quantidade: "Quantidade" + i,
        Unidade: "Unidade" + i,
        Preco: "Preco" + i,
        Desconto: "Desconto" + i,
        IVA: "IVA" + i,
        SubTotal: "SubTotal" + i
    });
}

tabelaBody.empty();
$.each(entidades, function (indice, entidade) {
    var novaLinha = $(tmplDetails.render(entidade));
    novaLinha.data("Entidade", entidade);
    
    tabelaBody.append(novaLinha);
});

documento.on("click", "#vendaTabela input[name='btCreate']", function () {
    var novaEntidade = {};
    var novaLinha = $(tmplCreate.render(novaEntidade));
    novaLinha.data("Entidade", novaEntidade);
    
    tabelaBody.append(novaLinha);
});

documento.on("click", "#vendaTabela input[name='btEditar']", function () {
    var linha = $(this).closest("[data-type]");
    var entidade = linha.data("Entidade");
    var novaLinha = $(tmplEdit.render(entidade));
    novaLinha.data("Entidade", entidade);
    
    linha.replaceWith(novaLinha);    
});

documento.on("click", "#vendaTabela input[name='btSalvar']", function () {
    var linha = $(this).closest("[data-type]");
    var txtCodigo = $("[name='txtCodigo']", linha);
    var txtDesignacao = $("[name='txtDesignacao']", linha);
    var txtQuantidade = $("[name='txtQuantidade']", linha);
    var txtUnidade = $("[name='txtUnidade']", linha);
    var txtPreco = $("[name='txtPreco']", linha);
    var txtDesconto = $("[name='txtDesconto']", linha);
    var txtIVA = $("[name='txtIVA']", linha);
    var txtSubTotal = $("[name='txtSubTotal']", linha);
    
    var entidade = linha.data("Entidade");
    entidade.Codigo = txtCodigo.val();
    entidade.Designacao = txtDesignacao.val();
    entidade.Quantidade = txtQuantidade.val();
    entidade.Unidade = txtUnidade.val();
    entidade.Preco = txtPreco.val();
    entidade.Desconto = txtDesconto.val();
    entidade.IVA = txtIVA.val();
    entidade.SubTotal = txtSubTotal.val();    
    
    var novaLinha = $(tmplDetails.render(entidade));    
    novaLinha.data("Entidade", entidade);
    
    linha.replaceWith(novaLinha);
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://www.jsviews.com/download/jsviews.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.foundation5.zurb.com/foundation.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.foundation5.zurb.com/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="vendaTabela">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th data-class="expand">Cód.</th>
            <th data-hide="phone">Designação</th>
            <th data-hide="phone">Qnt.</th>
            <th data-hide="phone,tablet">Uni.</th>
            <th>Preço</th>
            <th>Desconto</th>
            <th>IVA</th>
            <th>Sub-Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="btCreate" type="button" value="Criar" /></td>
            <td colspan="8"></td>
        </tr>
    <tfoot>
<table>
    

<script id="tmplDetails" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <tr data-type="details">
        <td><input name="btEditar" type="button" value="Editar" /></td>
        <td>{{:Codigo}}</td>
        <td>{{:Designacao}}</td>
        <td>{{:Quantidade}}</td>
        <td>{{:Unidade}}</td>
        <td>{{:Preco}}</td>
        <td>{{:Desconto}}</td>
        <td>{{:IVA}}</td>
        <td>{{:SubTotal}}</td>
    </tr>
</script>

<script id="tmplEdit" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <tr data-type="edit">
        <td><input name="btSalvar" type="button" value="Salvar" /></td>
        <td><input name="txtCodigo" type="text" value="{{:Codigo}}" /></td>
        <td><input name="txtDesignacao" type="text" value="{{:Designacao}}" /></td>
        <td><input name="txtQuantidade" type="text" value="{{:Quantidade}}" /></td>
        <td><input name="txtUnidade" type="text" value="{{:Unidade}}" /></td>
        <td><input name="txtPreco" type="text" value="{{:Preco}}" /></td>
        <td><input name="txtDesconto" type="text" value="{{:Desconto}}" /></td>
        <td><input name="txtIVA" type="text" value="{{:IVA}}" /></td>
        <td><input name="txtSubTotal" type="text" value="{{:SubTotal}}" /></td>
    </tr>
</script>

<script id="tmplCreate" type="text/x-jsrender">
    <tr data-type="create">
        <td><input name="btSalvar" type="button" value="Salvar" /></td>
        <td><input name="txtCodigo" type="text" value="{{:Codigo}}" /></td>
        <td><input name="txtDesignacao" type="text" value="{{:Designacao}}" /></td>
        <td><input name="txtQuantidade" type="text" value="{{:Quantidade}}" /></td>
        <td><input name="txtUnidade" type="text" value="{{:Unidade}}" /></td>
        <td><input name="txtPreco" type="text" value="{{:Preco}}" /></td>
        <td><input name="txtDesconto" type="text" value="{{:Desconto}}" /></td>
        <td><input name="txtIVA" type="text" value="{{:IVA}}" /></td>
        <td><input name="txtSubTotal" type="text" value="{{:SubTotal}}" /></td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

Comment: Agradeço-lhe desde já a colaboração e ajuda. Testei e está bastante completo, mas para o que estou a fazer, e para o nível exigido é um bocado complexo :D De qualquer forma Obrigado e merece o meu voto

Comment: Acredito que uma vez que você entenda o `jsRender`, o script em si fica facil de entender, até pq a unica coisa que ele faz é substituir um template pelo outro.

Answer (score 3):

**1.** Você pode resolver utilizando classes nas colunas e id's nas linhas para identificá-las. Por exemplo:

```
<tr id="linha1">
    <td class="numero">123</td>
    <td class="nome">Teste</td>
</tr>
<tr id="linha2">
    <td class="numero">123</td>
    <td class="nome">Teste</td>
```

```
var $numero = $("#linha1 .numero"); // coluna número na linha 1
```

---

**2.** Seguindo o exemplo anterior, você poderia fazer algo assim:

```
var subTotal = 0;
var $linhas = $("#minhaTabela tbody > tr");
// aconselho a usar o tbody na seleção para evitar selecionar o header e o footer

// percorre todas as linhas
$linhas.each(function() {
    // o this refere-se a linha
    var qtd = $(".quantidade", this).html();
    var vlr = $(".valor", this).html();

    // tenta converter para float e retorna 0 caso esteja em branco
    qtd = parseFloat(qtd) || 0;
    vlr = parseFloat(vlr) || 0;

    subTotal += qtd * vlr;
});

$("#subTotal").html(subTotal);
```

Para atualizar o subtotal ao adicionar uma linha é simples: coloque o código acima em uma função e chame novamente sempre que necessário.

---

**3.** Não entendi sua dificuldade aqui, você não sabe adicionar um autocomplete? Por você já utilizar o jQuery, pode utilizar o jQueryUI. Veja a [página de exemplo](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

Comment: Desde já agradeço a sua ajuda. Olhando ao ponto 1 da sua resposta, a minha dúvida é a seguinte: Eu no meu html só tenho um 'tr' onde defino o id que quero. Se atentar à minha função de adicionar linha, o que ponho nesse 'tr' para ir encrementando o id quando adicionar a linha nova?

Comment: Se possível utilize um contador. Caso contrário, uma solução bem dinâmica é utilizar o número de linhas atuais, por exemplo: `var id = 'linha' + $("#minhaTabela tbody > tr").length;`.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Não estou a entender esta parte: var $numero = $("#linha1 .numero"); // coluna número na linha 1
Fiz o console.log($numero) e o retorno é um objeto, pode explicar-me melhor para que serve ou o que faz essa linha?

Comment: Ele irá retornar um objeto jQuery. Tente, por exemplo, executar `console.log($numero.html())`. Você está utilizando este objeto jQuery no seu código, mesmo sem perceber.

Comment: retorna-me undefined :s Tenho isto: <thead><tr id="tr0">                                                       <th>Cód.</th></thead> <tbody>                                                        <td class="codigo"></td></tbody>  ... var $codigo = $("#tr0 .codigo");

Comment: Você está confundindo um pouco os seletores css. O seletor `#tr0 .codigo` irá procurar pelo elemento com classe `.codigo` **dentro** de um elemento com id `#tr0`. Faça o teste novamente com um html assim: `<table><tr id='tr0'><td class='codigo'>123</td></tr></table>`.

Comment: Dessa forma funciona :D Mas eu não posso ter o Header na minha tabela? isto é os <th></th> ?

Comment: Pode sim, mas de uma olhada novamente no código html que você tentou antes: `<thead><tr id="tr0"> <th>Cód.</th></thead> <tbody> <td class="codigo"></td></tbody>`. A coluna `.codigo` não está dentro da linha `#tr0`.

Comment: Já pus da forma que queria mas tou com um problema agora. Eu com o codigo quero ir buscar a designaçao. Para tal, estou a usar o var id = $(".codigo",this).html(); dentro do each das linhas. Se eu fizer o console log, ele faz o print de tudo. No caso do subtotal, está a funcionar direito porque ele pega o valor certo, mas para ir buscar a designação em que tenho de passar o id, tenho o metodo getDesignacaobyId(id) dentro do each das linhas e como percorre todas as linhas ele pega sempre na primeira designação. Sabe como posso dar a volta a isto ?

Comment: Segue o mesmo exemplo de como obter o valor. Adiciona uma classe para a coluna desejada e para obter basta executar `$(".designacao", this).html()` dentro do loop.

Comment: Eu segui exatamente da mesma maneira, mas o problema reside aqui: eu tenho dois each's: $linhas.each(function (){...e depois para ir buscar a designacao por ajax tenho ...  if (data.length > 0) {
                        $.each(data, function (key, value) {... logo dentro deste ultimo each, o this ($(".designacao", this).html()) não funciona.

Comment: Acredito que seja melhor você criar uma nova pergunta para este problema.

Comment: ok assim o farei então